# Export All E-MailAdresses Office365 PowerShell

Tags: powershell, get, office365

I'm using this command to get all MailAdresses of our Recipients in Office365

```
Get-Recipient -ResultSize Unlimited | select DisplayName,EmailAddresses | Format-Table -AutoSize | out-file $ExportPath\AlleMailAdressen-$DateTime.txt
```

My Problem here is, that it doesn't select ALL e-mail adresses, it selects max. 4 Mail Adresses per Recipient. But some of our recipients have more than 4 mail Adresse. How can I force Powershell to really Export EVERY Mail Adress?

Comment: If you run Get-Recipient | Select -Expand EmailAddresses  on specific mailbox (with more then 4 emailladdresses) do you get all results or only 4 as well?

Comment: If I run it on a specific Mailbox, I get all adresses. But I'm not able to write `select -exand DIsplayName, EmailAdresses` because "expand doesn't work for DisplayName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this. it works just as I wanted it to.

```
Get-Recipient -ResultSize Unlimited | select DisplayName,{$_.EmailAddresses -like 'smtp:*'} | Export-csv $ExportPath\AlleMailAdressen-$DateTime.csv
```

Thanks fo your Help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Text files in such cases, it cut the results,
Instead, Remove the Format-Table and Use Export-CSV like this:

```
Get-Recipient -ResultSize Unlimited | 
Select DisplayName,@{N="EmailAddresses";E={$_.EmailAddresses | Select -ExpandProperty SmtpAddress }} | 
Export-csv $ExportPath\AlleMailAdressen-$DateTime.csv -NoTypeInformation
```